# Better routes in rails with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working on a movie application in Rails. I have a controller/view for the actor. When passing params to the actors controller i want the URL to be pretty. Now it looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/actors/show?actor=Hayley+Atwell` and i want it to look like `/actors/show/Hayley+Atwell` or `/actors/Hayley+Atwell`.

How do i do this? My link in the movies view is:

```
<%= link_to a.name, {:controller => 'actors', :action => 'show', :actor => a.name}, :class => "label label-default" %>
```

My routes.rb is now like this:

```
get 'actors/show'
```

Comment: Why don't you make use of the actor's `id` instead of the actor's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in your ./config/route.rb file:

```
get '/actors/:actor', to: 'actors#show'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use friendly_id gem. It perfectly satisfies your needs!

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a series of refactoring advice as follow:

- Try to make use of the actor's id instead of the name
- Change the route to: get '/actors/show/:id', to: 'actors#show'

Then, you can now change the link in your view to something like:

```
<%= link_to a.name, {:controller => 'actors', :action => 'show', :id => a.id}, :class => "label label-default" %>
```

> Note: the `:` part in the `:id` of your route means that this could be interchanged to anything, and whatever comes in that place will be interpreted as the `id`. So, in `/actors/show/7`, the id of the actor is 7, you can now find the actor with this `id` in your controller action, and do anything you want with it.

Comment: Thanks, the route worked but i use name instead of id. In my controller i have `@actor = Actor.find_by(:name => params[:actor])`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right than you try to create `RESTful` routes anyway.

So I would recommend you to use the [Rails' `resources` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) in your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :actors   # If you want only the :show action than add:
                      # , only: [:show]
end
```

This automatically creates the proper routes for you.

To get the `names` into the URL you should use the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It has a great community and is very well tested.

Comment: The routes worked with my previous setup but i didn't get the looks i was after. I used the following in my routes.rb file and it gives me the result i was after. get '/actors/:actor', to: 'actors#show'